# jstree input element in a node don't have focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have this code:

```
<div id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            ind impianto 1
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input id="crea1" name="crea1" type="text" placeholder="anno">
                    <button onClick="creaquestionario(1)">crea</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The declaration of tree is:

```
$("#tree").jstree({
    edit: true
});
```

When I open the node the focus of input not work I have to hold down the mouse on it and then write the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jsTree first create a node, then edit it:

```
var parentNodeId = '#root';
var node = $('#tree').jstree().create_node(parentNodeId, 'New node');
$('#tree').jstree().edit(node);
```

To edit a selected node use:

```
var nodeToEdit = $('#tree').jstree().get_selected();
$('#tree').jstree().edit(nodeToEdit);
```

And in your html:

```
<ul>
    <li id="root">ind impianto 1</li>
</ul>
```

Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/onqhp05b/)

Comment: the code of tree is dinamically created in php, can I exec `.edit(node)` from the clicked node?